# C++ expected primary expression before in derived class constructor

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I know a lot of questions named just like this, but any of them couldn't help me to solve my problem.

These are the constructors in my **tree.h:**

```
Tree();
Tree(string name, int season, int lifeTime, int height, int leafType);
```

And these are their implementations in **tree.cpp:**

```
Tree::Tree() : Plant()
{
    this->lifeTime = 0;
    this->height = 0;
    this->leafType = -1;
}

Tree::Tree(string name, int season, int lifeTime, int height, int leafType) : Plant(string name, int season)
{
    this->lifeTime = lifeTime;
    this->height = height;
    this->leafType = leafType;
}
```

I am getting `expected primary-expression before name` error. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

`Plant(string name, int season)` needs to be `Plant(name, season)`.  You are calling a function not declaring one so you don't include the parameters type in a function call.